# Storm UI topology not working

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-storm, hadoop-streaming, apache-storm-flux

We are executing a Storm topology in `LocalCluster`.
Storm topology is executing fine and able to connect Storm UI (8090).
But Storm UI is not displaying the running topology information.

```
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
```

and submitting like:

```
bin/storm jar bin/StormTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.abzooba.storm.twitter.TwitterTopologyCreator Twitter
```

Answer (score 1):

`LocalCluster` does not have UI support... Thus the UI you are seeing belongs to a different Storm cluster.

To be more precise: `LocalCluster` is not really a cluster; it's a local JVM process that executes the whole topology (mimicking a real Storm cluster). Thus, `bin/storm jar ...` does not send the topology to any cluster but runs a local JVM (I assume, that `bin/storm` blocks). If you want to submit to a real cluster (and get an UI, you need to use `StormSubmitter`).