# Storm UI not showing topology

Tags: apache-storm

We are executing a Storm topology in `LocalCluster`. Storm topology is executing fine and able to connect Storm UI (8090). But Storm UI is not displaying the running topology information.

```
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
```

and submitting like:

```
bin/storm jar bin/StormTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.abzooba.storm.twitter.TwitterTopologyCreator Twitter
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033280/storm-ui-topology-not-working

Answer (score 4):

The Localcluster does not support topology UI.
If you really want to see the topology with a single machine, you can build the single node cluster, which you should run one zookeeper, one storm nimbus and one storm ui thread on the same machine. To submit your topology to the cluster you should use `StormSubmitter` and  change your code `LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();` to following.

```
if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
  conf.setNumWorkers(3);

  StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
}
else {

  LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
  cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());
  Utils.sleep(10000);
  cluster.killTopology("test");
  cluster.shutdown();
}
```

The code indicates when you add args, it will send the topology to the cluster, otherwise, it will run it locally.

And make sure you have import StormSubmitter with `import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;`

Comment: How to close the submission like local cluster shutdown method ?